# How do I get this PHP function to work with usort()?

Tags: php, function, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

I copied and pasted the piece of code below from http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php :

```
<?php

function cmp($a,$b)
{            
    return strcmp($a["fruit"], $b["fruit"]);
}

$fruits[0]["fruit"] = "lemons";
$fruits[1]["fruit"] = "apples";
$fruits[2]["fruit"] = "grapes";

usort($fruits, "cmp");

while (list($key, $value) = each($fruits)) { 
    echo "\$fruits[$key]: " . $value["fruit"] . "\n";
}
?>
```

At first it gave some error about the $b variable. Now the new incessant error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testsort.php on line 4
```

I'm thoroughly confused as to the problem here.

Comment: its working. check again

Comment: Yes, it working fine

Comment: it is working fine in my testing file. You missed }. Each statement must ends up with a } in PHP.

Comment: @Shital: you mean with ;. I don't see where I missed out a semi-colon.

Comment: go to testsort.php and check the line no : 4

Answer (score 0):

When I copied and pasted the code, some strange characters were part of it. These were invisible within notepad but revealed by VS Code IDE. Removing them allowed the code piece work.